# Count unique values of a column where 2 other columns meet certain criteria

Tags: excel

Count unique values of a column where 2 other columns meet certain criteria. Assume column A is a list of Claim Numbers that repeat because each claim has multiple bills in multiple months (month is column B and location is column C), each row represents a bill. I need to be able to count the unique claim numbers with the criteria of month=3 and location="Chicago"

```
-Claim #   Month   Location
-1234      3       Chicago
-1234      3       Chicago
-1234      3       Chicago
-1234      3       Chicago
-3215      3       Chicago
-3215      3       Chicago
-3215      3       Chicago
-1334      4       Chicago
-1334      5       Chicago
-1235      3       Philadelphia
```

The answer here should be 2

Comment: And where's the code you've tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: Try using PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Give this small macro a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = 3 And Cells(i, 3).Value = "Chicago" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            c.Add Cells(i, 1), CStr(Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox c.Count
End Sub
```